# I have a problem with the "for" function in R

Tags: r

First of all, I would like to make it clear that English is not my mother tongue and I don't speak it well, so I'm sorry for any mistakes.

I'll present the line where I'm having problems below.

```
vetor = iris$Sepal.Length

for (i in vetor) {
mean = mean(vetor)
  SD = sd(vetor)
  zscore = ((i-mean)/SD)
  print(paste("The z score number", 1:150, "is",  zscore))
}
```

What I wanted to happen is that it returned

"The z score number 1 is ..."

"The z score number 2 is ..."

And so on. In fact, he actually returns it to me, but when he finishes he starts again and repeats it at least 13 times. I don't know why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to calculate the z-score for each value in the `iris$Sepal.Length`.  You don't need a loop to do this: R is vectorised by default, meaning that it works on every value in a column at the same time.

So, you can do what I think you want without using a loop at all:

```
# Calculate the mean
mean = mean(vetor)
# Calculate the SD
SD = sd(vetor)
# Calculate the z-scores of every value in the vector, all at the same time
zscore = ((vetor-mean)/SD)
# Format the output as required.
print(paste("The z score number", 1:150, "is",  zscore))
  [1] "The z score number 1 is -0.897673879196766"   
  [2] "The z score number 2 is -1.13920048346495"    
  [3] "The z score number 3 is -1.38072708773314"    
  [4] "The z score number 4 is -1.50149038986724"    
  [5] "The z score number 5 is -1.01843718133086"    
  [6] "The z score number 6 is -0.535383972794483"   
  [7] "The z score number 7 is -1.50149038986724"    
  [8] "The z score number 8 is -1.01843718133086"    
  [9] "The z score number 9 is -1.74301699413542"    
 [10] "The z score number 10 is -1.13920048346495"   
<output truncated>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

I have to do this in the "for" because it was like the teacher asked.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your code in the following way:

- It would be much more efficient to move the calculations of both `mean` and `SD` out of your loop as they are needed to be calculated only once and not in every iteration
- I decided to use sequences of indices of your `vetor` with `seq_along` function and get the actual values by subsetting `[[]]`

When you apply `seq_along` on a vector it returns all the indices corresponding to each element, in this case it returns `1, 2, 3, ..., 150`. About the two brackets you could use only one as for a vector it does not make a difference. But when it comes to a data frame or a list subsetting with one bracket returns an object of the same class (data frame and list) but 2 brackets will simplify the result and it returns a vector.

```
vetor <- iris$Sepal.Length
mean <- mean(vetor)
SD <- sd(vetor)

for (i in seq_along(vetor)) {
  zscore <- ((vetor[[i]] - mean) / SD)
  print(paste("The z score number", i, "is",  zscore))
}

[1] "The z score number 1 is -0.897673879196766"
[1] "The z score number 2 is -1.13920048346495"
[1] "The z score number 3 is -1.38072708773314"
[1] "The z score number 4 is -1.50149038986724"
[1] "The z score number 5 is -1.01843718133086"
```

For more information you could gain considerable insight from this [book](https://bookdown.org/rdpeng/rprogdatascience/) by professor Roger D Peng.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!

I have two questions about your code. The first is what the command "seq_along" does. And the other is about the part "vetor[[i]]". Why the two brackets?

Comment: I added some notes :) You're welcome by the way.

Comment: I also added a link containing a fantastic book for you to read.

Comment: I have no words to express my gratitude. Seriously, thank you very much. I will make a lot of use of this book

Comment: No problem, you're welcome just read it many times carefully.

Answer (score 0):

```
data("iris")
vetor = iris$Sepal.Length

for (i in vetor) {
  mean = mean(vetor)
  SD = sd(vetor)
  zscore = ((i-mean)/SD)
}
print(paste("The z score number", 1:150, "is",  zscore))
```

### Output:

```
[1] "The z score number 1 is 0.0684325378759866"   "The z score number 2 is 0.0684325378759866"  
  [3] "The z score number 3 is 0.0684325378759866"   "The z score number 4 is 0.0684325378759866"  
  [5] "The z score number 5 is 0.0684325378759866"   "The z score number 6 is 0.0684325378759866"  
  [7] "The z score number 7 is 0.0684325378759866"   "The z score number 8 is 0.0684325378759866"  
  [9] "The z score number 9 is 0.0684325378759866"   "The z score number 10 is 0.0684325378759866" 
 [11] "The z score number 11 is 0.0684325378759866"  "The z score number 12 is 0.0684325378759866" 
 [13] "The z score number 13 is 0.0684325378759866" ...... so on
```